# How to deal with files recorded using Android MediaRecorder

Tags: android

I am using the following sample from Android website, for Audio recording

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

The recording is working well.

I am sending the recorded audio file to the server.

What are the best practices to decode files recorded on Android ?

I am trying to convert the uploaded recorded audio file,

From AMR file to MP3 or Wav or PCM

So far no luck,

Any help or direction appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: AMR files can be "viewed" on QuickTime, if you want to transcode them, you need to use a library or a third party program like Media Coder.

Comment: Thank you Rafael :), we got an AMR player, it is not playing amr files recorded Android but it can play, sample AMR files from the web

Comment: I am searching for a way to convert the audio file recorded on Android to standard PCM on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the file encoding and header was altered when save on the server, that is why it was marked invalid by AMR players or decoders.